# How to override save() method in a component

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.1

Where and how I am overriding the save method in Joomla 3.0 custom component ?

Current situation:

Custom administrator component.

I have a list view that displays all people stored in table. 
Clicking on one entry I get to the detailed view where a form is loaded and it's fields can be edited.

On save, the values are stored in the database. This all works fine.However, ....

When hitting save I wish to modify a field before storing it into the database. How do I override the save function and where? I have been searching this forum and googled quiet a bit to find ways to implement this. Anyone who give me a simple example or point me into the right direction ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the prepareTable function in the model file (administrator/components/yourComponent/models/yourComponent.php)

```
protected function prepareTable($table)
{
    $table->fieldname = newvalue;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just adding this for anyone who wants to know the answer to the question itself - this works if you explicitly wish to override the save function. However, look at the actual solution of how to manipulate values!

You override it in the controller, like this:

```
/**
 * save a record (and redirect to main page)
 * @return void
 */
function save()
{
    $model = $this->getModel('hello');

    if ($model->store()) {
        $msg = JText::_( 'Greeting Saved!' );
    } else {
        $msg = JText::_( 'Error Saving Greeting' );
    }

    // Check the table in so it can be edited.... we are done with it anyway
    $link = 'index.php?option=com_hello';
    $this->setRedirect($link, $msg);
}
```

More details here: [Joomla Docs - Adding Backend Actions](http://docs.joomla.org/J1.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Adding_Backend_Actions)

Answer (score 2):

The `prepareTable` in the model (as mentioned above) is intended for that (prepare and sanitise the table **prior to saving**). In case you want to us the ID, though, you should consider using the `postSaveHook` in the controller:

```
protected function postSaveHook($model, $validData) {
    $item = $model->getItem();
    $itemid = $item->get('id');
}
```

The `postSaveHook` is called **after save is done**, thus allowing for newly inserted ID's to be used.

Comment: Hi Masaia, I have overriden the save function in my child-controller and model. When I save a new record and after saving is executed in my model, it returns to the save function of the child-controller, the id is unknown for a new record in the save function of the child controller,  so the redirection is with id=0! I read on different forums that the postSaveHook() is therefore but how? How is the PostSaveHook() related to the save function of the controller? For example how do I get the value of $itemid in the save funtion, according to the joomla framework?